# Can a paired t-test be applied when there is no strict pairing but data come from same individual?

Tags: t-test, paired-data

The question is if it is possible to apply a paired t-test in the following situation:

Let's say we have conducted an experiment to measure how long does it take to perform a task under two different conditions. We have only one individual taking part in the experiment and we perform several measures in both conditions (let's say 300 measures under condition1 and 500 measures under condition2).

We want to figure out if we have enough evidence to state that there is a difference in the mean delay before response, more specifically that condition1 requires more time to complete the task.

To make it clearer a possible experiment may be:

we have one guy, running 100 meters 30 times and we measure the performances. 20 times this is done under sunlight and 10 times without sunlight. Can we use a paired t-test to provide evidence for the alternative hypothesis?

Comment: It depends on how you interpret your experimental objective.  *This* experiment can only assess how long it takes for *this individual* to perform the task.  It provides no legitimate basis to generalize to other individuals.

Comment: I perfectly agree with that point but what t-test should be used? Paired or unpaired? Because it is the same individual, but there is no natural correlation between the various measures (there are even more measure for one condition than the other)

Comment: What is the population parameter you want to make inference on?

Comment: I don't see any pairing, either.  Doesn't the lack of any pairing make your question moot?

Comment: The experiment is meant to check if we have enough evidence to state that (for example) under sunlight this person on average runs faster.
I know there is no pairing, but there still is a relation between the "two groups" since it is always the same subject.

Comment: Is there a strict ordering of equivalent tests under each condition? If each run under each condition was recorded with the same sequencing (enough pre experiment rest to ensure equivalent baseline, matched sleep, diet, time of day, day of week...) then for each run you give fixed rest and recovery protocols... In the end you can only use data points that can be directly compared (so must be same number in each). This gives different insight composted to unpaired and the question becomes will be what is that insight? That depends on the details.

Comment: The key here is that you need to be sure you have controlled for all possible biases otherwise what you end up measuring with a paired T test is the extent of bias in your experiment.

Answer (score 2):

There is no pairing in this situation, so I cannot see how a paired t-test could be applied. But you could use the non-paired t test for comparing two groups, or maybe better a permutation test.  More details/context would be needed to say much more.